# What's in xcode console with scanf ,when want a number but input a char?

Tags: xcode, macos, console

xcode 5.0
when I run following code:

```
void guessNum(){
    int answer = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    int turn = 0;

    answer = arc4random() % 100 + 1;

    while (guess != answer) {
        turn++;

        NSLog(@"Guess #%i: Enter a number between 1 and 100", turn);
        scanf("%i", &guess);

        if (guess > answer) {
            NSLog(@"Lower!");
        }
        else if (guess < answer) {
            NSLog(@"Higher!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Correct! The answer was %i", answer);
        }
    } // end of while loop

    NSLog(@"It took you %i tries", turn);
}
```

when I type a character, just like a in xcode debug console, program run automatic and print:

```
 ...
2013-11-18 10:47:39.719 donglix[15115:303] Higher!
2013-11-18 10:47:39.719 donglix[15115:303] Guess #1932: Enter a number between 1 and 100
2013-11-18 10:47:39.719 donglix[15115:303] Higher!
2013-11-18 10:47:39.720 donglix[15115:303] Guess #1933: Enter a number between 1 and 100
...
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

["`scanf()`"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) reads the input you've typed in and, because of your "`%i`" (integer) format string, is expecting to take that input and drop it into a number.

If you used "`%s`" as your format string, then you would take the input as a C-style character array (and have to convert those characters if you wanted to get the integer value out of that).

For example, you can replace this line:

```
scanf("%i", &guess);
```

with something like this:

```
char stringToConvert[256]; // if you type more than 256 characters, you'll crash
sscanf("%s",&stringToConvert);
guess = atoi(stringToConvert); // this function converts the string into an integer
```

If you type in the character "`a`", [scanf converts that to 97 in the ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: what's 'drop it into a number'? this program should be to input one and print the answer, why it run automatic which not I expect?